# map and store results in nested tibbles

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to map multiple models over some data and store the results in something similar to a nested tibble or multiple lists. I would like to apply the models in the same pipe. I run the following:

```
data(iris)
df <- iris %>% 
  filter(Species != "setosa") %>% 
  mutate(Species = +(Species == "virginica"))

var_combos <- expand.grid(colnames(df[,1:4]), colnames(df[,1:4])) %>% 
  filter(!Var1 == Var2)

map2(
  .x = var_combos$Var1,
  .y = var_combos$Var2,
  ~select(df, .x, .y) %>% 
    mutate(
      Species = df$Species
    )
) %>%
  map(., ~glm(Species ~ ., data = ., family = binomial(link='logit')))
```

Which gets me a nice maps logistic model. How can I store this model in a nested tibble or a list and then `mutate` and add more models to be stored next to it, such as:

```
 ...   %>%
      map(., ~glm(Species ~ ., data = ., family = binomial(link='logit'))) %>% 
      map(., e1071::svm(Species ~ ., data = ., kernel = "polynomial"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looping over elements of columns of 'var_combos' with `map2`, `nest` the 'data' by creating a dummy column, `map` over the  'data' and then create `list` of models as new column

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)    
out1 <- map2(
     var_combos$Var1,
     var_combos$Var2, ~  
       df %>%
           select(Species, .x, .y) %>%
           group_by(grp = 'grp') %>% 
           nest %>%
           mutate(models = map(data, ~ { 
           list(glm(Species ~ ., data = .x, family = binomial(link='logit')),
                e1071::svm(Species ~ ., data = .x, kernel = "polynomial") )
      })))
out1[1:3]
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   grp [1]
#  grp   data               models    
#  <chr> <list>             <list>    
#1 grp   <tibble [100 × 3]> <list [2]>

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   grp [1]
#  grp   data               models    
#  <chr> <list>             <list>    
#1 grp   <tibble [100 × 3]> <list [2]>

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   grp [1]
#  grp   data               models    
#  <chr> <list>             <list>    
#1 grp   <tibble [100 × 3]> <list [2]>
```

---

Checking the 'models'

```
out1[[1]]$models
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]

#Call:  glm(formula = Species ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = .x)

#Coefficients:
# (Intercept)   Sepal.Width  Sepal.Length  
#    -13.0460        0.4047        1.9024  

#Degrees of Freedom: 99 Total (i.e. Null);  97 Residual
#Null Deviance:     138.6 
#Residual Deviance: 110.3   AIC: 116.3

#[[1]][[2]]

#Call:
#svm(formula = Species ~ ., data = .x, kernel = "polynomial")


#Parameters:
#   SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
# SVM-Kernel:  polynomial 
#       cost:  1 
#     degree:  3 
#      gamma:  0.5 
#     coef.0:  0 
#    epsilon:  0.1 


#Number of Support Vectors:  98
```

The reason for nesting is to avoid storing the models repeating each row of the 'data' unnecessarily with `mutate`.  Here, the `data` is a `list` and at any point we can `unnest` to make it 'long' format

```
 library(tidyr)
 out1 %>% 
       map(~ .x %>% 
              unnest(c(data)))
```

Now, will see the 'model' `list` gets repeated for each row.  So, it would be better to store in a `list` column or even extract the 'models' as a separate dataset

#### Update

If we wanted to `flatten` the 'models'

```
map(out1, ~ .x %>% 
        mutate(models = list(flatten(models)) ) %>%
        unnest(c(models)))
```

Comment: Thanks! works exactly how I wanted it to. What is the purpose of the `grp` `group_by()` here? Is it only for the `nest()` function?

Comment: @user113156  `nest` needs a column.  So, I created a dummy one otherwise it shows some warnings and also the data format would be ugly

Comment: Okay thanks, I thought that was the case. I am looking at the `models` list and see that it is a list of 100 (the number of observations in the data). Why does each observation obtain a model? Are they all the same models? Should `mylist[[1]]$models` be a list of 2, instead of a list of 100 and then a list of 2 (2 here, 1 for each ML model).

Comment: @user113156 When you do `mutate`, it just replicates for each row to make the number of rows same, so basically recycling.  It is not efficient to store the models

Comment: Thanks!, I replaced `mutate` with `summarise` and now I obtain just a single model. Although `map(~ .x %>% 
        unnest(c(data)))` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @user113156 yes because `summarise` only does return the grouping variable and the column concerned.  Here, the `mutate` step for 2 models is stored in a `list` and the number of rows is 1?

Comment: @user113156 If you check my `out1[[1]]`, there is only a single row for `data` as it is stored as a `list` column.  I meant after `nest`ing

Comment: Perhaps I could `nest` the `data` into a list and then just have a list of 12 with 2 nested lists - one for `data` and the other for `models`. I am just thinking when I expand this to many more observations and more models it will take up a lot of memory.

Comment: @user113156 I would store it in a `list` as I showed in `out1[[1]]`, then there would be only 12 rows (total for all the list element)

Comment: Yes, apologies, this is how I wanted it. I had attached to the pipe `map(~ .x %>% 
              unnest(c(data)))` which was unnesting the data and confusing me.

Comment: @user113156 I showedd the `unnest` as an additional step in case you wanted it.  Also, from the 'model', you could extract the components with `broom::tidy` (but not all models have methods from tidy)

Comment: One final comment with this data. When I go to `out1[[1]]$models` I have a single list of `[[1]]` so I have to go to `out1[[1]]$models[[1]]` to see the 2 models. So the 2 models are located at `out1[[1]]$models[[1]][[1]]` and `out1[[1]]$models[[1]][[2]]` respectively. How can I unlist them such that the single additional list `[[1]]` is removed and the 2 models will be located at `out1[[1]]$models[[1]]` and `out1[[1]]$models[[2]]`. I have tried add `unlist` to the code but cannot get it working.

Comment: Nevermind I think this works `models_list %>% 
  map(., ~unlist(., recursive = FALSE))`

Comment: @user113156 I updated the post with `flatten` and `unnest`, so there will be 'n' rows of 'n' model